# Google Maps - download ONLY country (without surroundings)

Tags: downloading, google-maps

Google Maps for mobile (android) has a feature that you can download offline map, however it *seems* to me that you can only select area with fixed ratio, therefore you are selecting a huge area that you actually don't want.

Is there a way to change this select frame or to download some specific "country"? (But not anything from the surrounding countries? :)

Comment: I thought this is more of a general Google Maps - app question, but probably  isn't :)